# Function for change color of series?

Tags: highcharts

I want to change the colors of series..

this the function:

```
      function coloriamo(){
var ipocentro= this.point.y;

if(ipocentro<=50){
    return '#ff0000';
}

else if((ipocentro >50)&&(ipocentro<=400)){
    return '#ffff00';
}

else if(ipocentro>400){
    return '#000000';
 }
}
```

My chart is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-scatter-draggable/

how i can to change the color ?

i tried  to insert that function in formatter function(), but nothing....

**EDIT**

If i set marker.fillColor in this way:

```
 plotOptions: {
   series: {
    marker: {
     fillColor: coloriamo(),
            }
           }
         },
```

when

```
 function coloriamo(){
  var ipo= this.point.y;
  if(ipo<50){
    return '#ff0000';
      }
   return '#ffff00';
  }
```

but doesn't work...

i tried also in this way but nothing:
http://jsfiddle.net/L9szetnj/

Comment: What formatter? It is better to include your own code than linking to example.

Comment: Hi Ondkloss, i don't have example.. I tried to include "formatter function()" (with the code of function in the first post) to "color:" .... But doesn't work. Is there anorher way? Do you understand what i want to do?

Comment: Aha, okay. So you tried `color: coloriamo()`. I see. But you are checking `this.point.y`. A series has more than one point, so what if one point is below 50 and another point is above 50?

Comment: Yes, but doesn't work

Comment: i try but nothing... color: (function(){
                var ipo= this.point.y;
                    if(ipo>7){
                        return '#ff0000';
                    }
                return false;
            }),

Comment: You can't use function to set color for the point, only color (string/HC object) is supported - see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.color).

Comment: to have a function where the color is specificed per point ? i don't believe that there isn't a way....  In the first post, with my function, i say that if "y" of series' point is <= 50, the color it will be red...

Comment: You don't have to believe ;) When API says `Color`, then certainly it's not `Function`. If you want to apply your logic, do it before creating chart - for each of points set color:  `data: [{ x:10, y:10, color: 'red' }, {x: 20, y:20, color: 'blue'}]`.

Comment: See the link (how do you think is made)? http://baering.github.io

Comment: Just the way I described.. see: `data: [{ marker: { fillColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.75)", lineColor: "#123F3F", lineWidth: 1, radius: 19.360000000000003 }, timeAgo: "31 minutes ago", x: -17.462, y: 1.5, z: 65.07499999999999 }]` and the same for each of the points.. You can check this by using console: `Highcharts.charts[2].usetOptions.series[0].data[0]`.

Comment: But how using the console??? Please Pawel, can you show me a small example? i don't know well highcharts..

Comment: I mean using JavaScript console - dev tools. But it won't change anything, you will need to use format I suggested (first comment or the second one). Just set `color` or `marker.fillColor`.

Comment: i don't understand :( :( is impossible to apply logic...

Comment: I don't receive notifications from this question, I'm curious why.. Anyway, read once again my first comment. And read API!

Comment: Pawel for me is very difficult to understand all API, because i'm italian, i don't speak and read english well, and in italian Language about highcharts there is NOTHING. Now, i read your first comment, and i understood, but i think is better (for my problem) your THIRD comment. Have you seen jsfiddle in another question ? i think is better create "marker and fillColor" for each value of my array.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve in fact doesn't depend on Highcharts, it's rather JS knowledge. Anyway, is that question somehow different from [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558973/for-loop-doesnt-work-in-highcharts) ? Unfortunately I don't know italian, so I can help in english only ;)

Comment: No it isn't different... and you are right about the JS knowledge. Thank you very much pawel !