# For Loop doesn't work in highcharts?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for my question, but i don't understand if i did a mistake, or for loop doesn't work in highcharts...

http://jsfiddle.net/dpev61ug/1/

if i write

```
 var myarray= [[1,1,1],
              [2,2,2],
              [3,3,3]
              ];


    function toalert(){         
        for (var s = 0; s < myarray.length; s++) {
              var arr = (myarray[s]); 
              alert(myarray);
             }
            }
```

in for loop, alert works only for first (index [0]) value of array...

Please see the code jsfiddle

Sorry :(

Comment: Your code in the question is different from the the one in the jsFiddle. Please update your question.. Then you will find in your code ` return ... ` - which exits from the function and return just one object..

Comment: Hello Pawel, the code in question was only an example. If with return we have only object (and exit from "for loop") how can i write "marker and fillColor" for each value of my array ?

Comment: Yes, it was only an example, which is working perfectly fine.. That may cause misunderstandings. Now, just store values in some local array, then return that array: http://jsfiddle.net/dpev61ug/3/

Comment: Yes !!! Pawel thank you very much !!!1